# Can conversion from a pandas DataFrame to a raw numpy array improve ML performance?

Tags: python, performance, numpy, pandas, scikit-learn

<strike>A pandas `DataFrame` has the limitation of fixed integer datatypes (`int64`). NumPy arrays don't have this limitation; we can use `np.int8`, for example (we also have different float sizes available).</strike> (Limitation no longer exists.)

**Will scikit-learn performance *generally* improve on large datasets if we first convert the DataFrame to a raw NumPy array with datatypes of reduced size (e.g. from `np.float64` to `np.float16`)?** If so, does this possible performance boost only come into play when memory is limited?

It seems that really high float precision is often unimportant to ML relative to computational size and complexity.

If more context is needed, I'm considering the application of ensemble learners like [RandomForestRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html) to large datasets (4-16GB, tens of millions of records consisting of ~10-50 features). However, I'm most interested in the *general case.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for RandomForestRegressor states that the input samples will be converted to `dtype=np.float32` internally.

---

*Below is the original answer, which addresses the issue of using custom `numpy` types in Pandas (the struck-through part of the question)*

You can use `numpy` dtypes in Pandas. Here is an example (from a script of mine) of importing a `.csv` file with specified column dtypes:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=[0, 4, 5, 10],
                 dtype={0: np.uint8,
                        4: np.uint32,
                        5: np.uint16,
                        10: np.float16})
```

You can change the dtype of an existing Series or of a column in an existing DataFrame using [`Series.astype()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
s = pd.Series(...)
s = s.astype(np.float16)

df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(np.float16)
```

If you want to change the dtypes of several columns in a DataFrame, or even of all columns, use [`DataFrame.astype()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(...)
df[['col1', 'col2']] = df[['col1', 'col2']].astype(np.float16)
```

Comment: I thought I saw some limitation regarding mixed types in pandas (even if only mixed across different Series). I'll see if I can find specifics.

Comment: Ok, I think this limitation is specific to reading data in; i.e. [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). I will give this a try and see if it works. Assuming it does, do you expect a performance boost?

Comment: What limitation? You can pass a `dtype` argument to `read_csv`, as I showed above. As for a performance boost, I don't know: profile your code. What you will definitely see is reduced memory usage, which for the large datasets you want to work with could be important.

Comment: I found [this example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pydata/QCL4n_rAOkg) that outlines my issue, showing an attempt at reduced precision (`int16`) resulting in `int64`. Maybe this limitation is specific to `read_csv` and overcome with `astype`. I'll try to report back soon. Also, I'm still curious whether *in general*, performance is improved through less precise datatypes.

Comment: That issue was solved by this pull request: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/pull/2708 (so since v0.11).

Comment: Also, just found this:
Unless otherwise specified, input will be cast to `float64`
from the [tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html)